# The operation could not be performed because the filter is in the wrong state GetCurrentBuffer

Tags: directshow

The operation could not be performed because the filter is in the wrong state

I am getting this error when attemting to run   hr = m_pGrabber->GetCurrentBuffer(&cbBuffer, NULL);.

Strange part is - it initially worked when I stopped the graph, now it fails on running or stopped graph.
So - what state it should be in??

The sample grabber code in MSDN I copied does not say if the graph should be stopped or running to get the buffer size - but the way it is presented the graph is running. I assume the graph should be running to fill the buffer, but I am not getting pass the sizing the buffer.

The graph is OK, all filters are conncted and renders as required, in may app and in GraphEdit.

I am trying to save the captured still frame into bitmap file so I need the capured data in the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buffering and `GetCurrentBuffer` expose you a copy of last known media sample. Hence, you might hit conditions "no media sample available yet to copy from" and "last known media sample is released due to transition to stopped state". In both cases the request in question might fail. Copy data from `SampleCB` instead of buffered mode and this is going to be one hundred percent reliable.

See also: [ISampleGrabber::GetCurrentBuffer() returning VFW_E_WRONG_STATE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/21091ecb-ad42-4533-b877-4467895641aa/isamplegrabbergetcurrentbuffer-returning-vfwewrongstate?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment)

Comment: Thanks,it seem every time I get somting working in DirectShow there is another and better way to do it. Pretty frustrating.

Comment: Don't blame DirectShow. Perhaps you have not just yet got in touch with alternates.

Comment: Thanks,it seem every time I get somethiing working in DirectShow there is another and better way to do it. Pretty frustrating. I did checked on Pause and in theory it should make sure the graph state is Ok. It is working so far, but returns Invaid function. So I'll take a look on SampleCB as you suggested. But why is it faikling when I am just looking for size? I suppose if it is in wrong stste it cannot tell the size of buffer required.

Comment: I hate this site - it thinks it is smarter than average bear.Why This time the "edit timeout : bit me.

Comment: The fail is pretty much expected: it just does not have any sample at all buffered to get you any result back. Also keep in mind that Sample Grabber is not "core DirectShow", it is just a side helper for those who don't want to step into writing filters. Hence the overall accuracy, nevertheless Sample Grabber is certainly a very popular component.

Answer (score 1):

Using GetCurrentBuffer is a bad idea in most cases. Proper way to use sample grabber is by setting your callback and receiving data in SampleCB.